# Small footprint databases

Tags: database, embedded, embedded-linux

I am searching database engine(s) for two applications:

1. For storing temporary logs < 100k rows, before uploading to main server, only write required, and way to dump (no select/filter required)
2. Storing a ~100k records for quick find by one column

I thought about just plain MySQL, but the problem is that this database should fit into embedded device with under 256MB of RAM, I am have full running Linux device so I think there is no limitation except memory usage.

Would prefer what there would exists NodeJS client for it

Answer (score 1):

The [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org//) database was the one implemented in android devices even the low specs ones. You can check if it is sufficient for you application. Also it doesn't require a server.

Comment: what about quick accessing row in 100k by column, I think it will be slower as it depends on fs and fs is not the fastest in embedded devices

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think that it will be faster than normal client-server model databases which deal also with the file system and adding extra abstraction layers that will cause - in my opinion - extra latency.